# Different constructor for subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have an abstract superclass with a constructor of the form

```
public classname(String name, int amount)
```

and want to create a subclass of that abstract class that instead of taking a String as its first parameter takes an integer value that represents a given String name, so e.g. 0 stands for some String, 1 for another and so on.

When I try to write a constructor of the form subclass(int number, int amount) I get an error of the form "implicit super constructor is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor."

Why is it not possible to create another, different constructor in the subclass?

Comment: It _is_ possible calling `super()`; however, this must be the _first_ statement in the subclass constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by others in derived class you need to invoke constructor of its super class using `super(arguments)`. Also this call must be first instruction in your constructor so you will probably face problem where you will need to determine value you want to place as `name` before calling constructor like

```
MyClass(int id, int amount){
    super("???",amount);
}
```

here we don't know yet what value to use in place of `"???"`. Unfortunately you can't use

```
MyClass(int id, int amount){
    if (id==1) super("foo",amount);
    else super("bar",amount);
}
```

One of possible solutions is to create separate method which will return correct name based on `id` and use it as `super` parameter like

```
MyClass(int id, int amount){
    super(choseName(id),amount);
}

private static String choseName(int id){
    if (id==1) 
        return "foo";
    else 
        return "bar";        
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrong question, you can write another constructor in the subclass, but as the super class has no default/no-argument constructor, you *have* to explicitely call the constructor of the super class you mentioned to ensure the invariance of the super class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I don't have a variable of type String, I can't call the constructor of the form (String, int), so do I necessarily have to create another parameterless constructor in the superclass then?

Comment: @eager2learn see my answer, it may give you hints. I use this pattern quite a lot, so I can guide you to some examples too

Comment: You could hold a static map of integers to strings in your subclass and call the super constructor using the value from the map (or you check the answer of @fge).

Comment: Note, amended my answer (forgot the `extends` clause). @Smutje: true, this can be done; OP doesn't say whether integer to string map is contiguous, so I chose a `List` by default. The link I pointed to goes even deeper than that, though...

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use static factory methods. Consider this:

```
public abstract class Amount
{
    protected static final List<String> IDENTIFIERS
        = Arrays.asList("idfor0", "idfor1" /* etc */);

    protected final String identifier;
    protected final int amount;

    public static Amount forIdentifierNumber(final int number, final int amount)
    {
        return new IdBasedAmount(IDENTIFIERS.get(number), amount);
    }

    protected Amount(final String identifier, final int amount)
    {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Then, in the same package:

```
final class IdBasedAmount
    extends Amount
{
    IdBasedAccount(final String identifier, final int amount)
    {
        super(identifier, amount);
    }
}
```

Call from code:

```
final Amount amount = Amount.forIdentifierNumber(0, 20100);
```

After that, it is only a matter of defining whatever methods are needed in the `Amount` class (either `final` or delegated to subclasses).

Of course, adapt to your code.

Edit: an example of static factory methods yielding classes with different internal state but the same behaviour: [here](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-core/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonschema/core/misc/key). `SchemaKey` is abstract, acts as an "interface" and has static factory methods within itself to generate concrete classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super()` in your subclass's constructor and hence explicitly call the super class's constructor.